# Display driver who's salary is greater than the Average salary of drivers according to their driver status

Tags: sql, oracle

I am supposed to get the drivers with the salary that is greater than the average salary of all drivers ordered by their status.. With the code I have written I am unable to use the "Order by" function through a subquery. The display is going to be the driver name, and driver status and their salary. Here's my code

```
dr_status = the driver status
dr_drvname = driver name
dr_salary = driver salary
driver = driver table

select dr_drvname,dr_drvstatus,dr_salary
from driver
where dr_salary > (select avg(dr_salary) from driver group by dr_drvstatus)
group by dr_drvstatus;
```

Comment: Can you give us the DDL and DML?

Comment: Why are you trying to order by dr_drvstatus when you are selecting the computed average? Won't that only return a single value? There's nothing to order there.

Comment: What does "I am unable to use" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say exactly?

Comment: i need to order the average salary according to their status which are "pay after" "Pay before" and "Do not reserve"

Comment: I think you might be looking for `group by`

Comment: oops yeah i meant group by. sorry

Comment: But even then, it will return multiple rows, so I'm not sure you will be able to compare dr_salary to the results of the sub-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this.

```
select dr_drvname,dr_drvstatus,dr_salary
from driver d1
where dr_salary > (
    select avg(dr_salary) from driver d2
    where d2.dr_drvstatus = d1.dr_drvstatus
)
group by dr_drvstatus;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using OLAP functions and avoiding a correlated sub-query, I'd probably write:

```
SELECT d.dr_drvname, d.dr_drvstatus, d.dr_salary
  FROM driver AS d
  JOIN (SELECT d2.dr_drvstatus, AVG(d2.dr_salary) AS avg_salary
          FROM driver AS d2
         GROUP BY d2.dr_drvstatus
       ) AS a ON d.dr_drvstatus = a.dr_drvstatus
 WHERE d.dr_salary < a.avg_salary;
```

The sub-query will only be executed once to generate the list of statuses and average salary for that status.  If written as a correlated sub-query (as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13806634/15168) by [jonhopkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053938/jonhopkins)), you run the risk of the optimizer not spotting that the sub-query can be converted to a non-correlated sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an aggregate function like AVG() you almost never need or want that sub-query to have an "order by" OR a "group by" clause. It has to return a single value to be used in a comparison... what order do you want the single value in? Which one of the grouped values should it compare on? You're making it crazy with options. ;-)

Try removing that bit and see... chop down the sub-select to just this:

`(select avg(dr_salary) from driver)`

Answer (score 0):

i think you want something like this?

```
select dr_drvname,dr_drvstatus,dr_salary, avg_sal
  from (select dr_drvname,dr_drvstatus,dr_salary, 
               avg(salary) over (partition by dr_drvstatus) avg_sal
          from driver)
 where dr_salary > avg_sal;
```

Comment: yup, exactly like that. Thanks. There's some functions that I didn't know about to write it in a certain way. This helps a bunch thank you.